# How to determine relative distance between 3 in-phase transmitters by analysis of received signal

Tags: fft, phase, distance-metrics

I would like to determine with high accuracy the relative distances between three RF transmitters a few meters apart by analysis of phase interference in the received wave, the receiver being at an undefined distance a few hundred meters away. Is there a simple method for this? The three RF transmitters can be arranged to transmit the same phase and frequency, or differing frequencies, whatever is required. Is there some kind of radar or reflection interferometry technique that exists and provides the information required, from reflectors?

Comment: You can use [time difference of arrival (TDOA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilateration#TDOA_geometry) measurements to calculate these distances. The easiest way is to transmit like signals from multiple transmitters simultaneously, then have a receiver observe all of them and estimate the time offsets between each. One method of doing so is cross-correlation.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out, it does calculate the similarities of 2 or more signals
http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/examples/measuring-signal-similarities.html